# Configuring a Gurobi C++ project using Eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse, gurobi

I found [THIS](https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360013194392-How-do-I-configure-a-new-Gurobi-C-project-with-Microsoft-Visual-Studio-2017-) tutorial on how to configure a Visual Studio project to be able to work with the Gurobi library, however I couldn't find a similar manual for Eclipse C++. Is there anyone who managed to make it work?